# S3/Cloudfront: how to list a folder's contents in a bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, salesforce, apex

I've written a method that signs URLs to read an S3 bucket that is accessed through Cloudfront:

```
private HTTPResponse signURL(String endpoint) {
    String keyPairId = 'keyPairId';
    String secret    = 'SOME_SECRET';
    String method    = 'GET';
    Datetime dt      = Datetime.now();
    Long l           = dt.getTime();
    Long expiryLong  = (l / 1000) + 3600;
    String expiry    = String.valueOf(expiryLong);
    String policy    = policy('http://' + cfhost + '/' + endpoint, expiry);
    String policyEnc = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(Blob.valueOf(policy));
    String rPolicy   = cfReplace(policyEnc);
    Blob mac         = Crypto.generateMac('HMACSHA1',
                                          Blob.valueOf(rPolicy),
                                          Blob.valueOf(secret));
    String signature = cfReplace(EncodingUtil.base64Encode(mac));

    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
    req.setMethod(method);
    req.setEndpoint('http://' + cfhost + '/' + endpoint + '?Policy=' +
        policyEnc + '&Signature=' + signature + '&Key-Pair-Id=' +
        keyPairId);

    Http http = new Http();
    HTTPResponse res = http.send(req);
    return res;
}
```

Now, my method works fine if the endpoint is set to `''`. If I put the folder name in the endpoint (like `00Q17000008LRcAEAW/*`) I get a bunch of errors in the XML response.

```
XMLNode[ELEMENT,Error,null,null,null,[XMLNode[ELEMENT,Code,null,null,null,[XMLNode[TEXT,null,null,null,null,null,NoSuchKey,]],null,], XMLNode[ELEMENT,Message,null,null,null,[XMLNode[TEXT,null,null,null,null,null,The specified key does not exist.,]],null,], XMLNode[ELEMENT,Key,null,null,null,[XMLNode[TEXT,null,null,null,null,null,00Q17000008LRcAEAW/*,]],null,], XMLNode[ELEMENT,RequestId,null,null,null,[XMLNode[TEXT,null,null,null,null,null,some_req_id,]],null,], XMLNode[ELEMENT,HostId,null,null,null,[XMLNode[TEXT,null,null,null,null,null,some_host_id,]],null,]],null,]
```

I can't list the whole bucket because it's too big for the 1000-key limit. How can I list the folder?

Comment: Single quotes is not for strings in Java.

Comment: I would strongly recommend using jets3t instead of hand-writing all this.

Comment: Yeah, it's not available on my platform.

Comment: Did you find a way around the 1000 record limit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the S3 docs for List Objects, [V1](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTBucketGET.html) and [V2](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/v2-RESTBucketGET.html) for what S3 expects.

In short, you have to supply the prefix and delimiter (almost always `/`) in the query string, not the path.  The path is always the root of the bucket, for object listings, e.g.:

```
https://dxxxexample.cloudfront.net/?delimiter=/&prefix=00Q17000008LRcAEAW/&...
```

This also means that if you have a [default root object](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-amazon-cloudfront-feature-default-root-object/) defined for the distribution, you can't also pull directory listings through the distribution.  You'd need a second distribution or you'd need to fetch object listings directly from S3 in that case.

In any event, bear in mind that object listings are relatively expensive, over 10× the price of a `GET` request, so using CloudFront to fetch them might make sense if caching the responses makes sense, or you might want to do something entirely different, for object listings.  I've been rolling out a setup using S3 event notifications, Lambda, and RDS, to store all the objects and their metadata in a separate near-real-time database, where I can get faster and more complete listings without the cost (and I can search objects based on their metadata).

Comment: Thanks for the in-depth information! That helps a lot.